# Rearrange the position of the values in the table

Tags: mysql, date

I am using MYSQL. I have a table containing a start date and an end date for a schedule.

```
    |      StartDate         |    FinishDate      |
    |Feb 1, 2016 11:50 AM    |Feb 2, 2016 3:37 PM |
    |Feb 2, 2016 4:29 PM     |Feb 3, 2016 8:16 PM |
    |Feb 3, 2016 8:17 PM     |Feb 3, 2016 8:34 PM |
```

What I was hoping to do is to get the dates where there are no schedule entries. 
The easiest way I thought of is to generate a new table wherein the values in the FinishDate and StartDate will be rearranged in this format (The FinishDate value in the first row, second column will be the value in the first row, first column, while the StartDate value in the second row, first column will be transported to first row, second cloumn, and so on):

Desired Output
Without allocation:

```
    |      StartDate         |    FinishDate      |
    |Feb 2, 2016 3:37 PM     |Feb 2, 2016 4:29 PM |
    |Feb 3, 2016 8:16 PM     |Feb 3, 2016 8:17 PM |
    |Feb 3, 2016 8:34 PM     |  -                 |
```

How can I achieve the desired output? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Try formatting your example data in a more legible way.

Comment: Are there other columns in the source table?

Answer (score 0):

MySql doesn't have window functions, so generating this kind of result is always tricky. One possibility is:

```
SELECT
  t1.FinishDate StartDate
, MIN(t2.StartDate) FinishDate

FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t2.StartDate > t1.FinishDate
GROUP BY 1
```

This will work well if your date columns are indexed and you have relatively small number of rows to process.